# MySQL MONTHNAME() from numbers

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to get the `MONTHNAME()` from just the number of the month (1-12)? For example if I have `6,7,8` is there any native way in MySQL to transform those into `June,July,August`?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the number to a date, and then back with `MONTHNAME()`

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(6, '%m'));

+---------------------------------+
| MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(6, '%m')) |
+---------------------------------+
| June                            |
+---------------------------------+
```

Warning: This could be slow if done over a lot of rows.

Comment: thanks for the warning. The query I am doing only goes back a year or two, so max 24 rows.

Comment: Perhaps could store month names in MEMORY table and INNER JOIN it. or apply that in application...

Comment: this only works if sql_mode is not NO_ZERO_DATE, otherwise it will return NULL

Answer (score 8):

A somewhat ugly way would be `SELECT MONTHNAME(CONCAT('2011-',8,'-01'));`

Answer (score 2):

Before reading Michael's great answer I had thought something like this

```
select elt(3,'January','February','March',....)
```

but his one is much better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Such way you can get different language weekname or month name

to localize the weekday:

```
`SELECT ELT( WEEKDAY('2004-04-10')+1, 'Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag','Sonntag');`
```

long version with month:

```
`SELECT DATE_FORMAT( '2004-04-10', CONCAT( ELT( WEEKDAY('2004-04-10')+1, 'Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag','Sonntag'),', %d. ', ELT( MONTH('2004-04-10'), 'Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni','Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'),' %Y'));`
```

--> Samstag, 10. April 2004

same for unix-timestamp:

```
`SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(1081548000), CONCAT( ELT( WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(1081548000))+1, 'Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa','So'),', %d. ', ELT( MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1081548000)), 'Jan.','Feb.','März','April','Mai','Juni','Juli','Aug.','Sept.','Okt.','Nov.','Dez.'),' %Y'));`
```

--> Sa, 10. April 2004

Answer (score 0):

try this: select monthname('2016-01-01') for January or select monthname('2016-03-01') for March

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
        `mktp_target`.`id` AS `id`, 
        `mktp_target`.`target_year` AS `target_year`,
        `mktp_target`.`target_month` AS `target_month`,
        monthname(concat(`mktp_target`.`target_year`,'-',lpad(`mktp_target`.`target_month`, 2, '0'),'-', '01')) AS `target_month_name`
    FROM
        `mktp_target`
```