# MYSQL: How to convert a string into a month (Number)

Tags: mysql, string-conversion, date-conversion

I have the short version of months: `JAN, FEB, MAR`, etc.

and would like to convert them to it's respective numeric value: `1, 2, 3`, etc

Also, I would like to be able to change back and forth between the numeric-month-value, to a "short" month name (`JAN, FEB, MAR`) and it's long version (`January, February, March`, etc)

**NOTE:** As @dipu-raj pointed out, this is not a duplicate because I am asking the opposite to [MySQL MONTHNAME() from numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027129/mysql-monthname-from-numbers) **and the answer IS different as well BECAUSE** it requires different functions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027129/mysql-monthname

Comment: This question is not duplicate as flagged one. Here it is asking how to convert from Month Name to Month Number, but the flagged question has answer for convert from Month Number to Month Name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To convert abbrevation to full month name use:

```
mysql> select monthname(str_to_date('Mar','%b'));
+------------------------------------+
| monthname(str_to_date('Mar','%b')) |
+------------------------------------+
| March                              |
+------------------------------------+
```

To convert abbrevation to number use:

```
mysql> select month(str_to_date('Mar','%b'));
+--------------------------------+
| month(str_to_date('Mar','%b')) |
+--------------------------------+
|                              3 |
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: +1 - nice: my solution let the day be zero but I didn't consider that the year could also be zero; this is a lot cleaner.

Comment: Another way: `SELECT FIELD(month, 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')` where `month` is 1-12 will give you the month name from the number.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to familiarize yourself with the MySQL Date functions.  For your case `STR_TO_DATE()` and `DATE_FORMAT()` would seem to be most useful.  here is a link to the information:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 1):

**JAN** to its month number; substitute your column/value where you see `FEB` below:

```
date_format(str_to_date(concat(2012, 'FEB'), '%Y%b'), '%m')
                                     ^^^^^
```

**1** to its short month name; substitute your column/value where indicated:

```
 date_format(str_to_date(concat('2012-', 1), '%Y-%m'), '%b')
                                         ^
```

Use `%M` instead of `%b` as the last value above to get the long month name.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
    $date = 'Jan';
    echo 'Month number is '.date('n', strtotime($date)).'</br>';
    echo 'and its '.date('F', strtotime($date));
```

Use [PHP Manual - Date/Time Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more format options.