# How to get month name from number in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to get the month short name from just the number of the month in mysql ? 
for example : if I give 3, I need to get Mar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027129/mysql-monthname

Comment: MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(3, '%m')), I used this but, it is giving month full name. But, I want short name

Comment: @banalaramu use then **substring()** with **str_to_date()**.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(1, '%m'));//returns January
```

Also refer [this](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-monthname-function.php)

Comment: But I want short name like, Jan

Answer (score 2):

Use the following functions:
Month Number: `MONTH()`
Month Name: `MONTHNAME()`
You should use `monthname()` function.

Answer (score 1):

As per the manual, '%b' does just what you're after

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to retrieve this, date_format being one them, but it depends on how and what exactly you are trying to implement.
I suggest you take a look at the MySQL Date documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-12-01' + INTERVAL n MONTH, '%b') As Month_Name
```

change `n` to the month number.

Comment: try this one. just change `n` to your integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this should answer your query

```
SELECT left(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(1, '%m')),3) from dual
```

`dual` is used a spoof table when we dont want to refer a table in mysql but just want to execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(CONCAT(your_column)) as month from table_name;
```

Comment: hey there. adding a link to documentation would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is aged, but found it relevant today.

***Solution:***

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',LPAD( myMonthInteger ,2,'0'),'-01'),'%b')
```

Change the `myMonthInteger` value to your column name or month index value (1-12). Returns NULL for other values.

***Example using OP value of "3" for myMonthInteger:***

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',LPAD( 3,2,'0'),'-01'),'%b')
```

returns "Mar"

***Explanation:***

`LPAD( myMonthInteger ,2,'0')`

Adds a leading zero to the month integer if needed.

`CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',LPAD( myMonthInteger ,2,'0'),'-01')`

Creates a valid mysql date string with the current year and first day of month

`DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',LPAD( myMonthInteger ,2,'0'),'-01'),'%b')`

Formats the date string with '%b' type - short month name