# How can I transform the output of my "paymentMonth" column to display the months in text, in SQL?

Tags: sql

I would like the output of my "paymentMonth" column to display the months in text (January, February...) With my current code, what do i need to change/add for this to be achieved?

[image: 1]

Comment: Please share more details, like the "current code" and a **specific** question

Comment: Please post your table and code here in text and not as image. Posting as a Text would attract answers

Comment: Use [case ... when](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557209/21363224)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get month name from number in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298896/how-to-get-month-name-from-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
WITH
-- some of your input ..
indata(lastName,firstName,seller,paymentYear,paymentMonth,paymentTotal) AS (
          SELECT 'Jones','Barry'.   ,1504,2021,01,10549
UNION ALL SELECT 'Patterson','Steve',1216,2021,02,10223.8
UNION ALL SELECT 'Castillo','Pamela',1401,2021,08,53929.2
)
-- real query starts here ..
SELECT
  lastName
, firstName
, seller
, paymentyear
, date_format(
    cast(
        concat(concat(concat(paymentyear,'-'),paymentmonth),'-01') 
     as date
    )
  , '%M'
  ) as paymentmonth
, paymenttotal  
FROM indata;
```

| lastName | firstName | seller | paymentyear | paymentmonth | paymenttotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jones | Barry | 1504 | 2021 | January | 10549.0 |
| Patterson | Steve | 1216 | 2021 | February | 10223.8 |
| Castillo | Pamela | 1401 | 2021 | August | 53929.2 |