# SQL Statement Convert it to 1 to Jan, 2 to Feb and so on

Tags: sql, select, monthcalendar, str-to-date

As you seen the image below, the month is now 1 and 2. How can I convert it to 1 to Jan, 2 to Feb and so on. Below are my sql.

Help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance! :)

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT fbmenuname, 
                Sum(quantity)                        AS ordercount, 
                Month(Str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) AS month 
FROM   fb.fborders 
       INNER JOIN fb.fbmenu 
               ON fborders.fbmenuid = fbmenu.fbmenuid 
   INNER JOIN fb.fbrestaurant 
               ON fbrestaurant.fbrestaurantid = fbmenu.fbrestaurantid 
WHERE  fborders.status = 'completed' 
       AND ( Year(Str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = '2013' 
             AND fbrestaurant.fbrestaurantid = 'R0001' ) 
GROUP  BY fbmenuname, 
          Month(Str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: you want the **Jan** in `Update` statement or `Select` statement

Comment: If you're using SQL Server you can use an `UPDATE` and `DATENAME(MONTH, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027175/447356):

> You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the number to a date, and
>   then back with `MONTHNAME()`
>
> ```
> SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(6, '%m'));
>
> +---------------------------------+
> | MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(6, '%m')) |
> +---------------------------------+
> | June                            |
> +---------------------------------+
> ```

Use [`Left`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) Function to Trim the unwanted character

So try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT fbmenuname, 
                Sum(quantity) 
                AS ordercount, 
                Month(Str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) 
                AS month, 
                Monthname(Str_to_date(Month(Str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')), '%m' 
                          )) AS MonthName 
FROM   fb.fborders 
       INNER JOIN fb.fbmenu 
               ON fborders.fbmenuid = fbmenu.fbmenuid 
       INNER JOIN fb.fbrestaurant 
               ON fbrestaurant.fbrestaurantid = fbmenu.fbrestaurantid 
WHERE  fborders.status = 'completed' 
       AND ( Year(Str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = '2013' 
             AND fbrestaurant.fbrestaurantid = 'R0001' ) 
GROUP  BY fbmenuname, 
          Month(Str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

## [FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/30380)

Answer (score 0):

To assume you are using `MSSQL`, then the query for the same would be:

```
 SELECT DATENAME(month, 1)
 FROM fborders
```

and further rest of your query, you can use it in either `Update` clause or `Select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column `Month` to be int, you can try following query

```
UPDATE fborders
SET month=month+1
where month<12
```

This query will not update month DEC as month=13 doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can write SQL Query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fbmenuname, 
                Sum(quantity) 
                AS ordercount, 
                Datename(month, Dateadd(month, Month( 
                                Str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')), 0) - 1) AS 
                month 
FROM   fb.fborders 
       INNER JOIN fb.fbmenu 
               ON fborders.fbmenuid = fbmenu.fbmenuid 
       INNER JOIN fb.fbrestaurant 
               ON fbrestaurant.fbrestaurantid = fbmenu.fbrestaurantid 
WHERE  fborders.status = 'completed' 
       AND ( Year(Str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = '2013' 
             AND fbrestaurant.fbrestaurantid = 'R0001' ) 
GROUP  BY fbmenuname, 
          Month(Str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

declare @intMonth int
SET @intMonth=9

SELECT SUBSTRING('JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC ', (3 * 4) - 3, 3)
SELECT SUBSTRING('JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC ', (@intMonth * 4) - 3, 3)