# How to Convert 'September 2014' to '2014-09-01' in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I Want To Change The Date format 'September 2014' to   '2014-09-01' in Mysql 
     I tried with Below Query

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 1,2013','%M %d,%Y');
```

its working fine for 'May 1,2013' this format

but i am getting null while using 'September 2014' format

please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql MONTHNAME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027129/mysql-monthname)

Comment: No Its Working Fine... Maheswaran Ravisankar Sorry By Mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('September 2013',',1'),'%M %Y,%D');
```

EDIT: Mysql expects, all the date fields, so, the above work around is needed, when you don't have the day number beforehand.

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/44679)

Comment: Thanks but i am getting '2014-09-00' instead of '2014-09-01'