# SQL query to show monthly booking total

Tags: mysql, sql

Data in my table like below..

I need to show monthly booking summary

```
bookingdate   receipt
 01-02-2015     25
 01-02-2015     26

 01-03-2015     31
 01-03-2015     32
 01-04-2015     36
```

**Expected output**

```
Month             totalbooking
Feb - 2015             2
Mar - 2015             2
Apr - 2015             1
```

plz help me to Achieve my expected output...

I tried below query working but display all rows of month ...but i need to display only records of selected month...

```
SELECT RE.bookingdate AS bookingdate
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT RE.receipt_no) As TotalCount
FROM receipt_entry RE
WHERE str_to_date(RE.bookingdate,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate
    AND RE.city_name = :cityname
GROUP BY RE.bookingdate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e59b3/8/0) something you expect?

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(str_to_date(receipt_entry.bookingdate,"%d-%m-%Y")),'-',YEAR(str_to_date(receipt_entry.bookingdate,"%d-%m-%Y"))) AS dat,count(*) as cnt
FROM receipt_entry
GROUP BY dat;
```

Note: I'd advise you to store the date in `DATE` data type in MySQL. You won't need to call `str_to_date()` function every time.

Another note: I used `CONCAT()` there only to concatenate month and year in one field to adapt it to your desired output. Better just group by two columns: year and month

Comment: your query is perfect i think  but how to echo this date in this format...   Feb - 2015 not like this ...2-2015

Comment: see the updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e59b3/9 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027129/mysql-monthname-from-numbers

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following and change it as per your need

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+-------------+---------+
| bookingdate | receipt |
+-------------+---------+
| 2015-02-01  |      25 |
| 2015-02-01  |      23 |
| 2015-03-01  |      10 |
| 2015-03-01  |      12 |
| 2015-04-01  |      21 |
+-------------+---------+


select 
date_format(bookingdate,'%M - %Y') as `month`, 
count(distinct receipt) as receipt 
from test group by `month`;

+-----------------+---------+
| month           | receipt |
+-----------------+---------+
| April - 2015    |       1 |
| February - 2015 |       2 |
| March - 2015    |       2 |
+-----------------+---------+
```

You are saving dates as `varchar` so need to convert them to real date using `str_to_date` before applying the date_format, and also I see a where clause so in that case also you need to do the conversion using `str_to_date`, a good practice is to save dates in mysql native data types like `date` ,`datetime` or `timestamp` , this makes life simple.