# MySQL: How To Show Month By Name, Not Number

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to show the number of site leads per month. I am currently succeeding in most of that task, but I am unable to put the finishing touches on it.

***I need it to look like this...***

[image]

***I my work currently looks like this...***
[image]

***My code is as follows...***

```
SELECT CONCAT(clients.first_name, " ", clients.last_name) AS name, COUNT(leads.leads_id) as total_leads, MONTH(leads.registered_datetime)
FROM clients
JOIN sites
ON clients.client_id = sites.site_id
JOIN leads
ON sites.site_id = leads.site_id
WHERE leads.registered_datetime BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-06-31'
GROUP BY leads.registered_datetime
```

I need for the month to be shown as "January" and "February" rather than "1" and "2".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL MONTHNAME() from numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027129/mysql-monthname-from-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, you can simply use the `MONTHNAME` function in the same manner.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname

Comment: Thanks, bruh. Helped me out tons!