# MYSQL reverse engineering EXTRACT()

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a date field like `2014-12-30` and I did something like `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date) as yr_month` which returned a value like `201412`.

I'd like to retrieve the month from this new value, reverse engineer it back to the month. I tried `MONTH(yr_mnth)` and also `MONTH(RIGHT(yr_mnth, 2))`.

Any thoughts on how to retrieve the month from this field?

Comment: Any reason not to use MONTH(<original date field>)?

Comment: The original date field isn't what I want. The extract was done on `MIN(date)` denoting a 'cohort' in which the customer became a customer. I can go back and make some edits, but the data is aggregating nicely BECAUSE of this EXTRACT() on month and year. I'd prefer to find a solution on working with EXTRACT unless its not possible.

Comment: Perhaps this could help you on your journey:
    STR_TO_DATE(yr_mnth,'%Y%m')

Comment: Why do you need to call `MONTH()`. Doesn't `RIGHT(yr_month, 2)` return what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(yr_mnth, 2), '%m'));
```

This will get you the monthname from the month number. As you can see here: [MySQL MONTHNAME() from numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027129/mysql-monthname-from-numbers)