# How to convert timestap values to get Month name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been going round the internet looking for the best way to convert my timestamp values from my `dateadded` column : `2017-04-05 15:24:15` and obtain month name `APRIL` as the output.

Which is the best query to do this.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using XAMPP  @sqlzim

Comment: xampp isnt a database. I assume you mean mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL MONTHNAME() from numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027129/mysql-monthname-from-numbers)

Comment: If an Answer solves your problem, and you are satisfied that no other answer that might appear might prove more suitable, then you should accept the answer (choose the tick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql, use [**`monthname()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

```
select 
    dateadded
  , monthname(dateadded) as MonthName 
from t
```